# How to make a function to close a door when the player is not near it?

Tags: java, ibm-doors

So im making a wolfenstein 3d copy in Java and i've done a door list to change from 1 (closed) to 2(open) and i would want to make 2 to 1 when the player is not near it
ive got 2 variables for the player(yPos, xPos) and 2 for the door(row,column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that "ibm-doors" is not a good tag for your question ^^

Actually, this is a math question. You can calculate the distance between the player and the door with this formula (you may adapt the variable names and operators to your needs):

```
playerDoorDistance = sqrt((player.xPos - door.xPos)^2) + (player.yPos - door.yPos)^2)
```

where sqrt is the square root of what is between brackets, and ^2 is the square of what is between brackets.

Once calculated, you can just check that this distance is greater than a value of your choice to close the door.

If you prefer something more simple and that requires less calculation, you can just verify that `abs(player.xPos - door.xPos)` and `abs(player.yPos - door.yPos)` are greater than your chosen value (abs is the absolute value of what is between brackets) to close the door. It will verify that your player is outside a squared box around the door.

If you want no math at all, you can check this, which is the same as above (you may also adapt it to your needs):

```
if (player.xPos - door.xPos > chosenValue || door.xPos - player.xPos > chosenValue || player.yPos - door.yPos > chosenValue || door.yPos - player.yPos > chosenValue)
then closeTheDoor()
```

Comment: i didn't know what the ibm-doors tag was xD anyways thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. You can improve your question by removing the tag "ibm-door" and adding the tag "math", for other people who may be interested ;-)